# not open python as file or directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, python, development

I tried to develop pyarrow on my system for use it at python by using this site commands

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/development.html

in use the billow command

```
 cd arrow/python
python setup.py build_ext --build-type=$ARROW_BUILD_TYPE \
       --with-parquet --with-plasma --inplace
```

I got this error:

```
python: can't open file '/usr/bin/Python-3.7.0/PySwip/pyswip-0.2.3/setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

i used the ls command

```
$ ls -al python
ls: cannot access 'python': No such file or directory
```

what you suggest to me to solve this

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this? It looks like you have a messed up `/usr/bin/Python-3.7.0/PySwip/pyswip-0.2.3` Python package.

Comment: the version of ubuntu is 18.0